# Authorizing by different schemes by area using conventions in Razor Pages

Tags: c#, authorization, razor-pages

My Razor Pages application is structured like this:

- Pages

  - Index.cshtml
- Areas

  - Admin

    - Pages

      - Index.cshtml
  - Api

    - Pages

      - Index.cshtml

I want to allow anonymous access to any non-area page (anything in /Pages/). I want to use Windows Authentication for all pages in the Admin area and authorization via a bearer token for all pages in the Api.

I can do this using Authorize attributes directly on the PageModels and specifying the scheme.

```cs
//Non-area example
[AllowAnonymous]
public class IndexModel : PageModel
```

```cs
//Admin example
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "Windows")]
public class IndexModel : PageModel
```

```cs
//API example
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "ApiKey")]
public class IndexModel : PageModel
```

Then I can create a base PageModel for each of the 3 areas and inherit all PageModels for each area from the respective base PageModel.

Is there a way to accomplish this same thing using conventions?

```cs
services.AddMvc()
    .AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
    {
        options.Conventions.???
    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved it. The trick is an AuthorizeFilter can include schemes with a constructor overload.

```cs
var authorizeFilter = new AuthorizeFilter(new List<IAuthorizeData> {
    new AuthorizeAttribute()
    {
        AuthenticationSchemes = authenticationSchemes
    }
});
```

Then I had to write my own IPageApplicationModelConvention that will apply at the area level. The default methods work at folder and page levels. I used the source code from [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages/ApplicationModels/PageConventionCollection.cs) as a guide.

```cs
public class AreaModelConvention : IPageApplicationModelConvention
{
    private readonly string _areaName;
    private readonly Action<PageApplicationModel> _action;

    public AreaModelConvention(string areaName, Action<PageApplicationModel> action)
    {
        _areaName = areaName;
        _action = action;
    }

    public void Apply(PageApplicationModel model)
    {
        if(string.Equals(_areaName, model.AreaName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            _action(model);
        }
    }
}
```

I wrote some PageConventionCollectionExtensions which is how this is all done in [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages/DependencyInjection/PageConventionCollectionExtensions.cs).

```cs
public static class PageConventionCollectionExtensions
{
    public static PageConventionCollection RequireAuthenticationSchemesForArea(this PageConventionCollection conventions, string areaName, string authenticationSchemes)
    {
        if (conventions == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(conventions));
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(areaName))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException(nameof(areaName));
        }

        var authorizeFilter = new AuthorizeFilter(new List<IAuthorizeData> {
            new AuthorizeAttribute()
            {
                AuthenticationSchemes = authenticationSchemes
            }
        });

        conventions.AddAreaModelConvention(areaName, model => model.Filters.Add(authorizeFilter));
        return conventions;
    }

    public static IPageApplicationModelConvention AddAreaModelConvention(this ICollection<IPageConvention> pageConventions, string areaName, Action<PageApplicationModel> action)
    {
        if (action == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(action));
        }

        var convention = new AreaModelConvention(areaName, action);

        pageConventions.Add(convention);

        return convention;
    }
}
```

Finally I can register it all:

```cs
services.AddMvc()
    .AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
    {
        options.Conventions.AllowAnonymousToNonareas();
        options.Conventions.RequireAuthenticationSchemesForArea("Admin", "Windows");
        options.Conventions.RequireAuthenticationSchemesForArea("Api", "ApiKey");
    })
```

Note: The code for AllowAnonymousToNonareas is not defined here but it is very similar. I created a NonareaModelConvention with this Apply method:

```
public void Apply(PageApplicationModel model)
{
    if (model.AreaName == null)
    {
        _action(model);
    }
}
```

and wrote similar extension methods to tie it together.

Remember to turn on both anonymous authentication and windows authentication for the app.